# OpenEdge Progress 4GL Query returns (MISSING) after % sign

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_pay_terms NO-UNDO
            FIELD pt_terms_code LIKE payment_terms.terms_code
            FIELD pt_description LIKE payment_terms.description.
        DEFINE VARIABLE htt AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
        htt = TEMP-TABLE tt_pay_terms:HANDLE.

        FOR EACH platte.payment_terms
        WHERE (
            active = true
            AND system_id = "000000"
        )
        NO-LOCK:
        CREATE tt_pay_terms.
        ASSIGN
            pt_terms_code = payment_terms.terms_code.
            pt_description = payment_terms.description.
        END.

        htt:WRITE-JSON("FILE", "/dev/stdout", FALSE).
```

I have written this query and it returns data like this

```
[pt_terms_code] => 0.4%!N(MISSING)ET46
[pt_description] => 0.4%! (MISSING)DAYS NET 46
```

While I believe (from using a SQL query) that the data should be

```
0.4%45NET46 
0.4% 45 DAYS NET 46
```

I'm making an assumption that the % is probably some special character (as I've run into similar issues in the past).  I've tried pulling all the data from the table, and I get the same result, (ie, not creating a temp table and populating it with all the only the two fields I want).

Any suggestions around this issue?

I'm still very new to 4gl, so the above query might be terribly wrong.  All comments and criticisms are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you try this:

```
FOR EACH platte.payment_terms NO-LOCK
   WHERE ( active = true AND system_id = "000000" ):

  display
    payment_terms.terms_code
    payment_terms.description
  .

END.
```

You will see what the query actually returns.  (WRITE-JSON is adding a layer after the query.)  You will likely discover that your data contains something unexpected.

To my eye the "%" looks more like formatting -- the terms are likely 0.4%.

You then seem to have some issues in the contents of the description field.  My guess is that there was a code page mismatch when the user entered the data and that there is gibberish in the field as a result.

Comment: I will try it.  I have run into this issue before, and had to parse everything into a variable and then assign that variable to my temp-table field.